# How to access array of nested objects data in javascript? I need addperson details

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[How to access array objects add person details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChFKa.png)

Comment: Please provide your data and what you tried till now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**// GET FIREBASE STORE...**

```
import { onValue, push, ref } from 'firebase/database';
import { db } from '../Firebase/firebase-config';

  const [userNameData, setUserNameData] = React.useState([]);
    console.log('UserNameData first ==>', userNameData);
    React.useEffect(() => {
        return onValue(ref(db, 'username'), querySnapShot => {
            let data = querySnapShot.val() || {};
            let dataItems = { ...data };
            console.log('Useeffect return dataitems ===>', dataItems);
            setUserNameData(dataItems);
        })
    }, [])
    console.log('UserNameData second ==>', userNameData);
    let objectKey = Object.keys(userNameData);
    console.log('Hello keys ===', objectKey);
    let data = objectKey.length > 1 ? (objectKey.map(key => userNameData[key].username)) : null;
    console.log('data', data);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
    const someArrayWithObjects = [ 
        {
          object: {
            nestedObject: {
                someKey: "hello" 
            }
          }
        }
     ];
    const yourValue = someArrayWithObjects[0]['object']['nestedObject']['someKey']
    console.log(yourValue)
```

Comment: I tried using Because I have a nestedObject with a dynamic rendering nestedObject name. I can't guess the name. it's from backend side.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using multiple bracket notations.

```js
const array = [
  {xyz:{
    addperson:{
      address:"hello"
      }
    }
  ] 
  
  const access = array[1]['addperson']['address']
```

Comment: This code is not correct. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/74097384/17121621 for similiair answer with correct syntax

Comment: I tried using Because I have a nestedObject with a dynamic rendering nestedObject name.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the array items using `Array` methods, such as `map` or `forEach`.

If you want to directly read value of object property, then you can use `dot notation` (.), like:

`array?.[1]?.['-NE_OARSxk']?.addperson`

On the line above `array` is your array variable and I used `?.` - [Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining), because in your array you have some `null` values, so Optional chaining helps not to go into errors, when you directly refer to the property values of `Object`s s or elements of `Array`s.

Comment: It's good. but 
I tried using Because I have a nestedObject with a dynamic rendering nestedObject name.

Comment: @Loyalty_Thameem , cool, in this case you can iterate over the items of your array, e.g. as I mentioned in my answer and then use some of the built-in methods of `Object` constructor:  [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) or [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries).